# AWS SDK for Go - DynamoDb - Add multiple conditions to FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to filter a DynamoDb scan by multiple conditions using the expression builder. According to this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-amazon-dynamodb-expression-builder-in-the-aws-sdk-for-go/), attempting to add another condition in the builder will overwrite the previous condition. There must be some way to add another condition, but I have not been able to find a way to do it.

### This won't work

```
cond1 := expression.Name("foo").Equal(expression.Value(5))
cond2 := expression.Name("bar").Equal(expression.Value(6))
expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
    WithCondition(cond1).
    WithCondition(cond2).
    Build()
if err != nil {
fmt.Println(err)
```

}

### This is a working example with a single filter

```
filt := expression.Name("Artist").Equal(expression.Value("No One You Know"))
proj := expression.NamesList(
    expression.Name("SongTitle"),
    expression.Name("AlbumTitle"),
)
expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
WithFilter(filt).
WithProjection(proj).
Build()
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}

input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
  ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
  ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
  FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
  ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
  TableName:                 aws.String("Music"),
}
```

I have been able to accomplish this without using the expression buidler, but I would prefer to use the expression builder. How could I add another condition to that filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try adding multiple conditions with `And` , `Or` and `Not` methods from the `ConditionBuilder` struct. Example:

```
cond1 := expression.Name("foo").Equal(expression.Value(5))
cond2 := expression.Name("bar").Equal(expression.Value(6))
expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
    WithCondition(cond1.And(cond2)).
    Build()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/expression).

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had to be missing something.

Comment: I tried using similar expression, but got an error - buildTree error: unset parameter: ConditionBuilder

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically add conditions? For example: Let's say I've multiple keys which I want to match, that I do not know upfront., which will come as user input. So, using this approach, I will build an array of "conditions" but I'm failing to understand how to use the `And` to add all conditions in the final expression.