# DynamoDB multiple filter conditions, gives error - buildTree error: unset parameter: ConditionBuilder

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I am building REST APIs, using Lambda and DynamoDB in GO.

I need to query the data based on multiple filters.

The number of filters can be varying based on the number of query parameters user has provided, while calling the REST API.

As per the below post, I had developed the code to add multiple conditions.

[AWS SDK for Go - DynamoDb - Add multiple conditions to FilterExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073212/aws-sdk-for-go-dynamodb-add-multiple-conditions-to-filterexpression)

But when I invoke the function, I get below error, in the logs.-

> buildTree error: unset parameter: ConditionBuilder

The Filter expression is not applied and the scan returns all the results.

Here is the code snippet.

```
for queryParam, queryParamValue := range searchParams {
        fmt.Println("queryParam:", queryParam, "=>", "queryParamValue:", queryParamValue)
        if queryParam == “param1” {
            param1Condition = expression.Name(“param1”).Equal(expression.Value(queryParamValue))
        }

        if queryParam == “param2” {
            param2Condition = expression.Name(“param2”).Equal(expression.Value(queryParamValue))
        }   
    }


sampleExpr, errSample := expression.NewBuilder().
        WithCondition(param1Condition.Or(param2Condition)).
        Build()
    if errSample != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in building Sample Expr ", errSample)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("sampleExpr ", sampleExpr)
    }

    input := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  sampleExpr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: sampleExpr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          sampleExpr.Filter(),
        TableName:                 aws.String(deviceInfotable),
    }
```

But if I create the expression in different way, it works.

```
filt := expression.Name("param1").Equal(expression.Value("valu1")).Or(expression.Name("param2").Equal(expression.Value("value2")))
```

Comment: what's zero value of `param1Condition` and `param2Condition`?

Answer (score 0):

`ConditionBuilder` has `mode` field

```golang
type ConditionBuilder struct {
    operandList   []OperandBuilder
    conditionList []ConditionBuilder
    mode          conditionMode
}
```

The zero value of `mode` is `unsetCond`. When build condition, `unsetCond` raises the error.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/7798c2e0edc02ba058f7672d32f4ebf6603b5fc6/service/dynamodb/expression/condition.go#L1415

```golang
case unsetCond:
        return exprNode{}, newUnsetParameterError("buildTree", "ConditionBuilder")
```

In your code, if `queryParam != “param1”` and `queryParam != “param2”`, the `param1Condition` and `param2Condition` is zero value of ConditionBuilder, which fails on build.

Comment: In my case I have multiple conditions, 6. The end user may specify any number of conditions ( 0 to 6). So some conditions may not have any values.   Is there any way, we can still add a condition which doesn't have any value?