# Scan operation with FilterExpression having multiple conditions with "and" operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a lambda function in Go and using DynamoDB as my database.

I need to write a scan operation with multiple conditions (e.g. field1 = value1 and field2 = value2 and field3 = value3).

I am creating a `FilterExpression` string based on how many parameters/conditions are supplied by the user.

My filter expression is as below:

```
(#field1 = :field1Val) and (#field2 = :field2Val)
```

I am also providing the ExpressionAttributeNames and the ExpressionAttributeValues in the maps to the scan operation input. However, I am not getting any results (count = 0).

If I specify only one condition or if I use "or" operator instead of "and" operator, I get the results.

Looks like the second condition (#field2 = :field2Val), even if I use any field ( field3, field4, etc.)  is always resulting in "false".

Any pointers?

Where do I see the logs of this query/scan operation?

Comment: Could you add your code and table structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS SDK for Go - DynamoDb - Add multiple conditions to FilterExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073212/aws-sdk-for-go-dynamodb-add-multiple-conditions-to-filterexpression)

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem.

The filter condition string is correct -

```
(#field1 = :field1Val) and (#field2 = :field2Val)
```

I was iterating in a loop to find out which search parameters are specified by the user.

There was a mistake in the code, I was using the same variable name for all the attribute names.

```
attributeName := "field1"
attributeNamemap["#field1"] = &attributeName
```

This "attributeName" field was used for all the search parameters.
This was causing the problem, I used different variables and it started working.